# Stack Overflow is encouraging salutations while not allowing them

Tags: discussion, answers

I just noticed this friendly notice after posting a new answer:

> [image]

Great and awesome, however new users who see this might think "how friendly, let's be friendly in our own posts from now on" and start adding salutations, just to be faced with edits removing them which might easily escalate to edit wars.

I can think of two possible ways to minimize possible damage:

1. Allow salutations in posts and remove the filters that remove/block them automatically.
2. Change the message. Can't think of a different wording which will be proper, so maybe whole redesign of the banner so it contains "Answer similar questions" as hyperlink, then "Click to dismiss" button to  the right.

What do you think? Other ways? Leave it as it stands now and hope for the best?

Comment: Well, allowing Salutations is not an option [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @Arun of course it is. Lots of things changed in the 5.5 years since that post, SE is becoming more and more social.

Comment: Have you seen any evidence that new users are adding "thanks" to their posts? Since it comes _after_ the user posted and since it only appears after answers and since it looks like a UI element, I don't really think it's going to cause people to add such niceties to their posts.

Comment: @Jon not yet, and honestly not going to make any research, it's just a strong hunch I have, and something I might do myself as a brand new user.

Comment: I would wait to see if there's *actually* a problem (measurable uptick in salutations in posts/edit wars/whatever) before worrying about what action to take over it!

Comment: I like option 2, thank you!

Comment: @rene well played! No ice cream for you! :-)

Comment: After reading this, I think we should be doing more with ice cream.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to be clear:

**We are not against friendliness.** Or politeness. They are explicitly welcome.

Our resistance to some types of friendly discourse is a necessary cost due to our  need to control *noise*.  But it should only be applied when it is needed to offset some greater harm.

Personally, I'd *encourage* "thanks so much" comments, if it weren't for the fact that larger sites, like SO, tend to attract *dozens* of them.  Which makes the noise harm from them (especially to downstream readers) often greater than the positive influence from gratitude, feedback, etc.

When in doubt, assume more polite, more friendly, more cuddles with puppies are *good* for the community as whole, until such time as they get in the way or undermine other needs.

Comment: I don't think some people actually *believe* this. Some people state that they want the community to be "akin to an encyclopedia" (which will have no friendliness neither the opposite). I personally do not think that this is something to pursue, since **this is NOT an encyclopedia** per se. It can still achieve the status of a **knowledge hub** (if it hasn't already) while allowing these kind of "friendliness" (when they are not overly extended) since, opposite to encyclopedias, you ARE interacting with a human directly, you are having (some kind of) conversation.